# Minimum number of guesses to guess a sequence of five digits

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle

Related: [A building with 5 floors and 4 doors in each floor and a pool at the roof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4572779/a-building-with-5-floors-and-4-doors-in-each-floor-and-a-pool-at-the-roof)

The original question asked how to arrive at a solution. I am curious about finding a minimal solution. I will reword the problem to make it easier to understand:

A program stores a five-digit sequence that is unknown to the program's user. Each digit of the sequence is a $1, 2, 3,\text{ or }4$. A user can send a single digit to the program. The program will compare the sent digit to the sequence. If it matches the first digit of the sequence, the program will compare the next digit sent to the second digit of the sequence. This continues for the third, fourth, and fifth digits. Once the program successfully matches the fifth digit to the user's input, the user is informed their guess was successful and the program ends.

However, if a digit does not match, the program moves back to the first digit without informing the user. The only output from the program is success on the fifth digit. No failures are ever reported to the user. The following sequence of user inputs is guaranteed to eventually cause the program to end, regardless of which sequence is correct:

$$1,2,3,4,1,3,2,4,3,1,4,2,1,3,4,3,2,1,4,1,2,4,2,3,1,2,2,3,1,1,2,2,3,4,2,4,1,4,4,1,1,4,4,4,1,1,3,2,3,3,2,2,4,3,3,1,3,1,2,1,1,2,4,4,3,4,2,2,1,3,3,4,3,4,4,3,2,4,1,3,1,4,3,3,3,2,1,2,3,2,2,3,3,4,2,1,4,3,1,3,4,1,1,3,4,4,2,1,3,2,3,4,3,1,1,1,4,2,4,4,2,3,2,1,1,4,1,2,1,4,2,2,2,4,3,4,1,4,3,2,2,1,2,4,1,1,2,3,1,3,3,1,2,3,3,3,1,2,1,3,1,1,3,3,2,4,2,2,4,4,4,3,4,2,1,2,2,1,1,1,3,2,1,3,3,3,4,4,1,4,1,3,4,2,3,3,1,4,1,1,1,2,4,3,3,2,3,2,4,2,1,1,3,1,4,4,2,2,2,3,4,4,4,2,4,3,2,3,1,4,1,4,2,2,3,2,4,4,1,2,2,4,1,2,3,1,3,2,2,2,1,2,4,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,4,4,3,1,1,4,3,4,3,3,4,1,2,1,2,1,4,3,4,2,3,4,3,4,2,4,2,4,4,2,4,2,3,2,3,2,1,1,4,2,2,4,2,1,3,1,3,1,4,2,3,3,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,2,1,4,3,3,4,1,3,3,3,1,1,2,1,2,3,4,2,2,3,4,1,4,1,1,4,4,3,2,2,1,3,1,2,4,3,1,2,1,3,2,4,1,1,1,1,1,3,4,3,1,4,4,4,4,4,1,3,2,3,1,1,1,2,2,4,3,2,4,4,2,2,4,4,3,3,1,1,2,3,2,1,2,4,2,1,4,1,3,1,1,4,1,3,3,2,2,2,3,3,1,1,3,1,3,4,4,4,3,3,4,4,4,1,4,2,4,3,3,3,4,1,2,3,2,4,3,2,2,3,1,4,3,1,2,2,1,4,2,1,1,2,2,2,4,1,4,3,4,4,1,3,1,4,2,3,4,4,2,3,1,4,4,1,2,1,1,1,4,1,2,2,3,2,3,3,3,2,3,2,2,4,1,1,3,3,4,3,1,3,3,4,2,4,1,3,4,1,4,4,2,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,4,2,2,1,1,4,3,2,1,3,4,2,1,4,4,4,2,2,2,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,1,4,3,2,3,4,2,4,4,1,4,2,2,3,3,2,4,3,4,3,2,4,2,4,1,1,2,1,3,3,1,4,3,3,2,1,1,3,2,2,2,3,2,3,1,3,2,1,1,1,1,3,2,2,4,2,3,3,2,3,1,2,4,4,4,4,3,4,3,3,1,2,4,1,4,1,4,4,3,1,3,1,3,4,1,1,4,2,1,2,1,2,4,3,1,1,3,4,1,3,3,4,1,1,1,3,1,2,3,4,3,3,3,3,4,4,3,4,3,4,1,2,4,4,2,4,1,2,1,3,4,4,1,1,2,2,1,2,3,3,1,3,2,1,4,2,3,2,4,4,3,1,4,1,1,2,4,3,2,1,2,2,4,4,2,3,3,2,1,3,1,4,1,2,3,3,4,3,2,2,2,4,2,2,2,1,4,4,2,4,3,3,1,1,4,3,1,3,2,3,3,1,2,2,1,3,4,2,2,4,1,4,3,1,1,4,4,1,3,3,3,2,4,1,2,4,3,4,4,2,2,3,1,3,3,2,3,4,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,3,3,3,1,4,2,4,2,1,2,3,1,1,3,2,1,1,2,3,4,2,1,3,2,2,3,4,3,1,2,4,2,4,3,4,1,3,1,3,3,3,4,3,2,3,2,3,3,2,2,1,1,2,1,4,2,1,2,4,4,1,1,1,4,4,3,3,4,4,2,1,1,4,4,2,2,1,4,3,2,4,2,3,4,2,3,1,3,4,3,4,3,1,1,1,3,3,1,3,4,1,3,4,4,3,1,2,1,4,1,4,1,3,2,4,4,4,1,3,2,2,1,1,3,1,2,2,2,3,1,4,3,4,1,1,2,2,4,2,4,4,4,2,1,3,3,4,4,1,4,4,1,3,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,1,1,2,4,1,1,4,1,4,2,3,1,3,1,2,2,3,3,1,4,2,2,1,2,2,4,2,2,3,1,2,1,2,3,3,2,4,1,3,2,1,2,1,1,4,2,3,2,2,2,2,4,3,3,4,2,3,4,1,1,3,2,4,3,3,4,3,3,3,4,2,2,2,3,2,1,3,1,2,3,2,3,4,4,4,4,2,4,1,4,2,1,4,2,4,4,3,2,3,4,1,4,2,4,1,2,3,4,4,1,2,4,2,2,3,2,1,1,3,4,2,1,1,1,2,1,4,4,1,4,3,1,4,1,3,2,4,2,2,4,3,1,3,1,1,1,1,4,3,3,2,2,3,2,2,4,4,1,3,4,3,3,2,4,4,2,1,4,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,2,3,1,4,2,2,4,3,4,4,4,3,2,3,2,4,1,3,3,1,1,1,4,3,2,1,1,4,3,3,3,1,3,4,2,4,3,1,2,3,2,1,4,4,3,4,4,2,4,4,1,3,1,4,4,3,2,1,3,2,1,2,4,3,2,4,3,4,3,4,4,4,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,4,1,1,1,4,2,4,2,2,2,1,3,3,2,1,2,1,3,3,3,3,2,3,1,2,3,3,2,3,3,1,4,4,4,3,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,3,3,2,3,4,3,2,2,4,1,3,4,3,1,3,2,4,1,4,4,4,2,3,3,3,4,1,2,4,1,3,1,2,2,4,2,1,3,3,4,1,4,3,3,1,4,1,4,3,2,3,3,4,1,4,4,3,4,1,2,2,4,2,1,2,3,1,4,3,2,2,1,4,1,2,1,2,2,3,3,3,2,2,3,2,3,1,2,4,1,1,3,3,1,3,3,2,4,2,3,3,2,4,2,1,3,4,1,2,2,2,4,4,2,3,4,4,3,1,1,4,2,3,1,1,4,1,4,1,2,4,2,4,2,2,1,3,2,3,2,2,1,4,3,4,3,1,1,3,1,3,4,4,3,4,2,3,2,4,3,4,2,2,1,4,4,2,3,4,4,1,2,3,4,1,1,4,3,1,4,3,1,1,1,3,4,2,1,1,4,4,4,4,1,1,1,2,3,2,1,4,3,4,1,3,1,3,2,2,2,2,1$$

I have found shorter sequences of user inputs that still guarantee the program will end. My question is, what is the shortest possible sequence of user inputs that will allow the program to end successfully? Is it possible to find a shortest sequence of user inputs without an exhaustive search? Obviously, starting with the fifth input, it is possible that a maximum of one pattern has been matched in the previous five inputs, so a lower bound is $4^5+4 = 1028$. The sequence shown above is of length $1466$. So, the shortest is somewhere in that range.

Comment: This feels similar to the Haruhi problem. I might be wrong, though.